# Please bring back monospace fonts for the Markdown editor

Tags: bug, design, editor, fonts

When editing a question or answer (on multiple websites, including Stack Overflow, Code Review, and Database Administrators), the Markdown editor uses proportional fonts.  This is extremely annoying on sites that deal with lots of code blocks.

When asking a new question, it uses monospace — the way it was until recently, and the way it should be.